# sympy could not solve two equations that come from two planes intersecting

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

The following piece of code should solve two equations (shown in the picture below)
which represent two planes intersecting in a line.

```
import sympy as sm
x,y,z = sm.symbols('x y z ')
p1 = sm.Plane(sm.Point3D(0,0,0), (1,3,5))
p1Eq = p1.equation()
display(p1Eq)
p2 = sm.Plane(sm.Point3D(1,3,3), (-1,2,2))
p2Eq = p2.equation()
display(p2Eq)
sm.solve( (p1Eq, p2Eq), (x,y,z))
```

The output is shown in the picture below.

[image: output of code above]

You could say that the type for `p1Eq`, and `p2Eq` are not compatible with solve.
Then I tried the following:

```
eq1 = sm.Eq(p1Eq,0)
eq2 = sm.Eq(p2Eq,0)
x,y,z = sm.symbols('x y z ')
sm.solve( (eq1, eq2), (x,y,z))
```

Again, the output was an empty list.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

The symbols in the equation are created with real=True so you need to do the same or pass the symbols that you want to be used:

```
In [21]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')

In [22]: p1 = Plane(Point3D(0,0,0), (1,3,5))

In [23]: p2 = Plane(Point3D(1,3,3), (-1,2,2))

In [24]: p1Eq = p1.equation(x, y, z)

In [25]: p2Eq = p2.equation(x, y, z)

In [26]: solve([p1Eq, p2Eq], [x, y, z])
Out[26]: 
⎧     4⋅z   33     11   7⋅z⎫
⎨x: - ─── - ──, y: ── - ───⎬
⎩      5    5      5     5 ⎭
```

Alternatively create your symbols with real=True like the ones that are used by `Plane.equation` by default:

```
In [27]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z', real=True)

In [28]: solve([p1.equation(), p2.equation()], [x, y, z])
Out[28]: 
⎧     4⋅z   33     11   7⋅z⎫
⎨x: - ─── - ──, y: ── - ───⎬
⎩      5    5      5     5 ⎭
```

Comment: Great!.  `real=True``.  That was the key point.